# How to remove duplicate values and some particular values from dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, duplicates, dropdown

I have a drop down list and i assigned results of stored procedure to it. The stored procedure returns years from 1990 to 2050 and some of the values are duplicates(ex... 1990 multiple times, 1999: 4 times...etc). Now I want to REMOVE these duplicates and along with I need to SHOW only plus/minus 5 years only in the dropdown based on current year. for example, the current year is 2017, so i need to show from 2012(2017-5) to 2022(2017+5) in the dropdown.

Sample code I tried:

```
Public Shared Sub RemoveDuplicateItems(ddl As DropDownList)
    For i As Integer = 0 To ddl.Items.Count - 1
        ddl.SelectedIndex = i
        Dim str As String = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString()
        For counter As Integer = i + 1 To ddl.Items.Count - 1
            ddl.SelectedIndex = counter
            Dim compareStr As String = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString()
            If str = compareStr Then
                ddl.Items.RemoveAt(counter)
                counter = counter - 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To ddl.Items.Count - 1
        ddl.SelectedIndex = i
        Dim str As String = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString()
        If str <= Convert.ToString(Now.Year - 5) OrElse str >= Convert.ToString(Now.Year + 5) Then
            ddl.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But it is not working as expected. The first part is basically for removing duplicates, which is fine, when it comes to second part, I'm having issues with limiting plus/minus 5 years. Can someone please let me know how to resolve?

Comment: Select Distinct in sql statement?

Comment: @OneFineDay unfortunately I can't change stored procedure ..!

Comment: You can use a Hashset to avoid duplicated values

Comment: When deleting items in a for loop you have to go from end of list to beginning.If you remove item 2 then item 3 becomes to and you will skip this item.  So for loop should look like this : For i as Integer = ddl.Items.Count - 1 To 0 step -1

Comment: @jdweng you are probably on to something.  To me modifiying a collection you are currently iterating is a red flag.  Abhi can you clarify on how the output is unexpected.  You could provide the output in the question.  It might help people reverse engineer the problem.

Comment: I discovered this issue over 40 years ago when doing a Fortran Program in college.  Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2):

```
    'Get distinct items'
    Dim distinct = ddl.Items.Cast(Of Integer).Distinct().ToList()

    'Get -5/+5 range from now'
    Dim offsetPlus = DateTime.Now.AddYears(5)
    Dim offsetMinus = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5)
    Dim yearRange = distinct.Where(Function(x) x <= offsetPlus.Year AndAlso x >= offsetMinus.Year)

    'Clear and re-add items'
    ddl.Items.Clear()
    For Each item In yearRange
        ddl.Items.Add(item)
    Next
```

If your DropDownList items are really of type string you have to adjust the `Cast` in the `Distinct` call and add `ToString` to the `yearRange.Where` function.
But I would recommend to use Integer.